# Android: AlarmManager shows same notifications all the time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I create multiple notifications with different text. However, AlarmManager always shows notification with same text, replacing old notification if the previous one not swiped away. NOTIFY_ID is always different (debugged). Also I've found out that if I crash app in onRecieve method after showing notification it works fine... Here is the code:

```
public class Schedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        //next is notification code. //

        //get res.
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("appsettings", 0);

        String titleText = mPrefs.getString("titleText", "");
        String bigText = mPrefs.getString("bigText", "");
        int NOTIFY_ID = mPrefs.getInt("id", 0);

        //create intent.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        //get res.
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        //build notification.
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.statusbaricon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(titleText)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentText(bigText);


        //check vibration.
        if (mPrefs.getBoolean("vibration", true)) {
            builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 50 });
        }

        //create default title if empty.
        if (titleText.length() == 0) {
            builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_Title_Default));
        }

        //show notification. check for delay.
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
                .bigText(bigText).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

        ////
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int delay = mPrefs.getInt("delay", 0);
        int id = mPrefs.getInt("id", 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Schedule.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() /* + 1000 * 60 * delay */, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
    //store stuff to revoke in Schedule.
    mPrefsEditor.putString("bigText", bigText).apply();
    mPrefsEditor.putString("titleText", titleText).apply();

    Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
    schedule.setAlarm(context);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different `requestCode` for different `PendingIntent` with flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, 
                              notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**1.** From `setAlarm()` method send notification `id`, `titleText` and `bigText` to broadcast `receiver` through `intent` and also use flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

**Update `setAlarm()` method as below:**

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int delay = mPrefs.getInt("delay", 0);
    int id = mPrefs.getInt("id", 0);
    String titleText = mPrefs.getString("titleText", "");
    String bigText = mPrefs.getString("bigText", "");

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // send notification id, titleText and bigText with intent 
    // to use later when alarm triggers
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Schedule.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", id);
    intent.putExtra("TITLE_TEXT", titleText);
    intent.putExtra("BIG_TEXT", bigText);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() /* + 1000 * 60 * delay */, pendingIntent);
}
```

**2.** In your `onReceive()` method, get notification `id`, `titleText` and `bigText` from `Intent`.

**3.** Use notification `id` as `requestCode` for `contentIntent` and use `titleText` and `bigText` for notification `text`.

**Update `onReceive()` method as below:**

```
public class Schedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        // get id, titleText and bigText from intent
        int NOTIFY_ID = intent.getIntExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", 0);
        String titleText = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE_TEXT");
        String bigText = intent.getStringExtra("BIG_TEXT");

        // Create intent.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // use NOTIFY_ID as requestCode
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                NOTIFY_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // get res.
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        // build notification.
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.statusbaricon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(titleText)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentText(bigText);


        // check vibration.
        if (mPrefs.getBoolean("vibration", true)) {
            builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 50 });
        }

        // create default title if empty.
        if (titleText.length() == 0) {
            builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_Title_Default));
        }

        // show notification. check for delay.
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
                .bigText(bigText).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

        ////
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    ....................
    .......................... 
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Oh my. So much thanks for answer! I will learn it deeper now. Btw, may I mention you name as gratitude in next update? :)

Answer (score 0):

This `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is your problem.
based on what you want to do use different flag(s) in your code and that works as you expect!

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

for example: FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, ...  or don't use any flag at all (0).

`PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` forces your program to use pendingintent just once. be careful that calling `setAlarm` with different `putString` may not change the result.

EDIT:
put this lines in your `Schedule.java` line 33 and 34. this is going to change notification everytime but it is not a good solution, you should replace `"something different" + bigText` with different variable string.

```
String titleText = mPrefs.getString("titleText", "");
String bigText = mPrefs.getString("bigText", "");
SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsTextsEditor = getSharedPreferences("notifications", 0).edit();
bigText = "something different" + bigText;
titleText = "something different" + titleText;
mPrefsTextsEditor .putString("bigText", bigText).apply();
mPrefsTextsEditor .putString("titleText", titleText).apply();
```

Comment: Much thanks for your answer. But either FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or 0 it works in the same way. So sad.

Comment: how about pendingintent flag?

Comment: PendingIntent flag? I set PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT and it works same way. I set 0 and it works same way.

Comment: obviously you change your `bigText` and `titleText` in `mPrefsEditor`, right? do you use `apply` or `commit` after you change these?

Comment: sure thing. it works if I set notifications in the same way to show them immediately.

Comment: still got no answer.

Comment: please send here all code in which you set notification message with different titles and bodies.

Comment: project is open source. don't really want to paste a bunch of code here. here is link: https://github.com/NapoleonTheCake/notificatorro
Notifications are created in class MainActivity in method onClick_Notify. Alarm sets in activity Schedule. Folder with .java files: https://github.com/NapoleonTheCake/notificatorro/tree/master/source/app/src/main/java/com/cake/notificator

Comment: it is you who help me :) any idea why does it work so?